# Can't use spring-modules-validation with spring 3 

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, maven-2, maven

i have following pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- Maven Coordinates(groupId,artifactId,version):define a unique location for a project 
        CONSIDERING that groupId and artifactId combination must be unique.-->

    <!-- A groupId groups a set of related artifacts. Group identifiers generally resemble a Java package name. -->
    <groupId>com.spring.sample</groupId>

    <!-- The artifactId is generally the name that the project is known by -->
    <artifactId>spring_sample</artifactId>
    <name>Spring Sample Web App</name>

    <!-- The packaging element affects the steps required to build a project. -->
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <version>1.0.0</version>


    <!-- User-defined Properties -->
    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring-security.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</spring-security.version> 
        <tiles.version>2.1.3</tiles.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- a collection of internal and external dependencies -->
    <dependencies>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
            <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        -->


        <!-- Spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>

            <!-- Scope controls which dependencies are available in which classpath, and which dependencies are included with an application -->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- End Of Spring Dependencies -->

        <!-- Container-provided dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Provides database connection pooling services 
        (technique used for sharing server resources among requesting clients) -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>hibernate-commons-annotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- End Of Hibernate Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>


      <dependency>
      <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>8.1-407.jdbc3</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.3</version>
      </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <!-- A build lifecycle is an organized sequence of phases that exist to give order to a set of goals.
         Those goals are chosen and bound by the packaging type of the project being acted upon. -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>



    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>Maven Central</id>
            <name>Repository for Maven2</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>jboss</id>
            <name>jboss</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>javanet</id>
            <name>Repository for Maven2</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>google</id>
            <name>Google repository for Maven2</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-releases/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Bundle Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.libraries.release</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Library Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/release</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.libraries.external</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Library Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/libraries/external</url>
        </repository>



    </repositories>

</project>
```

when i add the dependency for :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-modules-validation</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

i am getting following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getResourceLoader()Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getResourceLoader()Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.configureScanner(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:100)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:83)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:69)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1114)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:280)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:100)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:298)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:241)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apparently you are experiencing the *JAR hell* issue. Change your dependency in `pom.xml` to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-modules-validation</artifactId>
    <version>0.8</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mock</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

If it does not help, try running:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
```

This will help you to find duplicated or overlapping JARs - then you can exclude them using the technique above.

Comment: Very good. It solved my problem! I liked the term JAR hell, I think it describes quite well our challenges on putting this controlled accident of integrated technologies operational. Sometimes our achievings I believe are slighlty inferior of putting men on moon.