# What happened to springmodules package in spring 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-modules

Recently while I was updating a project from spring 2.5.6 to 3, I couldn't find the relavent
org.springmodules package... Because of using spring 2.5 dependency I cannot use org.springmodules 0.8 version... Can anyone please tell me any what happened to the classes in this org.springmodules module and a place to find any more changes.. ?

thanx..

Comment: SpringModules is obsolete and no longer maintained.  Which functionality are you using it for?

Comment: I'm looking for ValangValidator or similar class

Comment: "An implementation of Validator that takes a Valang syntax string to define the set of validation rules it will apply. This instance is thread-safe." This is what it says in the api..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find any substitution you could exclude the spring 2.5 dependency of springmodules like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386191/cant-use-spring-modules-validation-with-spring-3).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I ran into a similar issue.. Upgraded to spring 4.x and see that springmodules validation was using a depreated spring API that got removed in 4.x.
The only solution (apart from trying to find another validation framework) we had was to fork the source code ourselves, fix it and use it.